# Impossible to correct problems, bad packages are in "keep as is" mode

Tags: r, linux

I'm trying to install the latest version of R (R.4x)
I am on Ubuntu 18.4 (bionic)
I tried many ways (eg. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart)
but, I have an error.

when I tape `sudo apt install r-base` , I have this error:

> Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait Construction de l'arbre des
> dépendances        Lecture des informations d'état... Fait Certains
> paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier que vous avez
> demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez la distribution
> unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore été créés ou ne sont
> pas sortis d'Incoming. L'information suivante devrait vous aider à
> résoudre la situation :
>
> Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
> r-base : Dépend: r-recommended (= 3.6.3-1bionic) mais ne sera pas
> installé E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets
> défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».

English error version;

> Reading package lists... Done Building the dependency tree Reading status >information... Done Some packages cannot be installed. This may mean that >you have requested the impossible, or, if you are using the unstable >distribution, that some packages have not yet been created or have not >been released from Incoming. The following information should help you >resolve the situation:

> The following packages contain unsatisfied dependencies: r-base : >Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.3-1bionic) but will not be installed E: >Impossible to fix problems, faulty packages are in "keep as is" mode.

Comment: It would be a lot better if you could translate the complete error tracing to English, as the actual information needed to debug is often found in tracebacks.

Comment: yes I did it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to tell you that I found a solution to my problem (if anyone gets the same error...)
The problem is that I damaged the sources.list file.
So what I did?
I delete completely this file

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then create an empty one

```
sudo subl /etc/apt/sources.list
```

in which I put :

> > #deb cdrom:[Xubuntu 18.04 LTS *Bionic Beaver* - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic >main multiverse restricted universe
> > deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
> > deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
> > deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe >multiverse
> > deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
> > deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse
> > deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
> > deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
> > deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
> > deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
> > deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
> > deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/

Finally, I installed R4.0.2 and it works ...

Hopefully, that can help.